# Select Table values dynamically

Tags: mysql

Not sure if it's possible via a query but bear with me.

Let's say I have the following table:(Let's call it: 'tables')

```
id | table
---------
1  | Table1
2  | Table2
3  | Table3
```

I'd like to create a query that selects data from the dynamic table name inside a row.

Something like:

```
select * from (select table from tables where id = 1)
```

Expected resulted from this query is all rows and columns from "Table1".

Is something like this can be done via MySQL?

I couldn't find any information about this so anything will probably help.

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: If I understand your question, You have x tables and another table which is "handles" them by id and next to it the table name.
I think you should read this simple lesson -> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Would a blob data type help here?

Comment: @Idoshhh Not quite sure how to use inner join here, do you have a query I could run so I can understand your answer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), possibly inside a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines.html) to accomplish this.

Also, as @strawberry says in a comment, this is a sign of bad design. Even if it's possible to solve you should probably rethink your design.

Comment: While you're correct that this is likely really bad design, there's times where you get roped into maintaining existing poorly structured databases...I should hope for the OP's sake, that isn't the case, but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you cant do this with one query, and you need a server side language to get this done in two steps,

first get the table's name by running this query

```
select table from tables where id = 1
```

then save the result in a vaiable , lets assume it is on PHP, `$tab`
now you can run your main query by integrating the `$tab` variable which contain the name of the table you look for, this will give a clear MySQL query to execute

```
select * from $tab
```

Comment: You're under the presumption that there's a php setup on the backend (or any back end programming language at all...) to work with.  That may or may not be the case, so this answer may or may not work for the OP.